# symfony2 router generator context problems

Tags: symfony, router

i've a problem with the router generator of symfony 
when i'm running 
`dump($this->container->get('router'));exit;`
 on a controller my router context is like this

```
#context: RequestContext {#306 ▼
-baseUrl: "/my-project/web/app_dev.php"
-pathInfo: "/accueil"
-method: "GET"
-host: "localhost"
-scheme: "http"
-httpPort: 82
-httpsPort: 443
-queryString: ""
-parameters: array:1 [▶]
```

}
But the same code but on mailer service i get this `#context: Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext {#312
   -baseUrl: ""
   -pathInfo: "/accueil"
   -method: "GET"
   -host: "localhost"
   -scheme: "http"
   -httpPort: 80
   -httpsPort: 443
   -queryString: ""
   -parameters: []
 }`

i found this problem after getting urls like 
**"http://localhost/bundleRoute/myRoute/7"** instead of 
**"http://localhost/my-project/web/app_dev.php/bundleRoute/myRoute/7"**

THANKS.

Comment: I think it is because i'm calling this service during a symfony command so there is no requests context so symfony router will create a new one 

` $this->context = $context ?: new RequestContext();` on the router class so it's logic to get empty context . I'm always searching for a solution for my problem to generate url when running console command

Comment: Hi there is my solution : Get the context after calling router service then set the baseUrl to the context then set the  new modified context to the router, and finally call generate method , i hope it helps. If i make mistake or there is another better solution  please let me know. 
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the request context for your application when parts of it are executed from the command-line: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html#configuring-the-request-context-globally